# Two-way partial search using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a PHP snippet that looks up a MySQL table and returns the top 6 closest matches, both exact as well as partial, against a given search string. The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT phone, name FROM contacts_table WHERE phone LIKE :ph LIMIT 6;
```

Using the above example, if `:ph` is assigned, say, %981% it would return every entry that contains 981, e.g. 9819133333, +917981688888, 9999819999, etc. However, is it also possible to return all entries whose values are contained within the search string using the same query? Thus, if the search string is `12345`, it would return all of the following:

- **12345**6789 (contains the search string)
- 8888**12345**00 (contains the search string)
- 999**12345** (contains the search string)
- **123** (is contained within the search string)
- **45** (is contained within the search string)
- **2345** (is contained within the search string)

Comment: tokenize the input string and add it to your search criteria. e.g. phone in (1,2,3,4,5...etc).

Comment: @Ambrish, Do you mean something like `WHERE phone IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,12,23,34,45,56,123,234,345...) OR phone LIKE '%123456%'`? I think that would be terribly slow.

Comment: @Jakar If you have index on PHONE column then it would be better. May be a better split algo would be a good idea (if input length is 5 then create tokens of length 3 & 4 only.

Comment: doing `WHERE IN ()` will not use an index, though, even if the index exists.

Comment: @Ambrish, The larger token size would certainly help a lot. I still expect that performance would become an issue with only a few hundred rows, though. I don't care to test it though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Jakar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec6b14/2

Answer (score 3):

You can do a lookup where the number is `LIKE` the column:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` 
    WHERE '123456' LIKE CONCAT('%',`stuff`,'%') 
        OR `stuff` LIKE '%123456%';
```

An index will never be used, though, because an index cannot be used with a preceding `%`.

An alternate way to do it would be to create a temporary table in memory and insert tokenized strings and use a `JOIN` on the temporary table. This will likely be much slower than my solution above, but it is a potential option.

Comment: Works like a charm; however, I am nervous about giving up on index since the table in question could potentially have millions of records and there could be a gazillion queries being fired all the time. Not using index would be a massive performance bottleneck. As for temp tables, the idea makes me squirm even more.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia, as far as I know, that's not going to be possible. Any time you lead with a `%`, indexes are thrown out. Even a simple `WHERE people.name LIKE '%eorge'` would be unable to use an index. If I think of a more performant solution, I'll post it here. But I don't think I'm going to.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the option of dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT
    phone
FROM
    contacts_table 
WHERE 
    phone LIKE :ph or
    phone = :val1 or
    phone = :val2 or
    phone = :val3 or
    phone = :val4 or
    phone = :val5 (so on a so forth)
LIMIT 6;
```

Where :ph will be your regular input (e.g. %981%) and valX is going to be tokenize input.

It would be good idea if you do the tokenizing smartly (say if input is of length 5 then go for token size of 3 or 4). Try to limit the number of tokens to get better performance.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec6b14/3)

If you using PHP then do something like:

```
foreach ($phone as getPhoneNumberTokens($input)) {
    if ($phone != "") {
        $where_args[] = "phone = '$phone'";
    }
} 
$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $where_args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use three tables. I don't actually know how performant it will be, though. I didn't actually insert anything to test it out.

`contact` would contain every contact. `token` would contain every valid token. What I mean is that when you insert into `contact`, you would also tokenize the phone number and insert every single token into the `token` table. Tokens would be unique. Kay. So, then you would have a `relation` table which will contain the `many<->many` relationship between `contact` and `token`.

Then, you would would get all contacts that have tokens that match the input phone number.

**Table definitions:**

```
CREATE TABLE contact (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, phone varchar(16), PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE(phone));

CREATE TABLE token (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, token varchar(16), PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE(token));

CREATE TABLE relation (token_id int NOT NULL, contact_id int NOT NULL);
```

**The query:**
There might be a better way to write this query (maybe by using a subquery rather than so many joins?), but this is what I came up with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_list.phone FROM contact AS contact_input
  JOIN relation AS relation_input
    ON relation_input.contact_id = contact_input.id
  JOIN token AS all_tokens
    ON all_tokens.id = relation_input.token_id

  JOIN relation AS relation_query 
    ON relation_query.token_id = all_tokens.id
  JOIN contact AS contact_list
    ON contact_list.id = relation_query.contact_id

  WHERE contact_input.phone LIKE '123456789'
```

**Query Plan:**
However, this is with no data actually in the database, so the execution plan could change if data were present. It looks promising to me, because of the `eq_ref` and key usage. 
[image]
I also made [an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a3c3/3/0) demonstrating this.

**Notes:**

- I didn't add any indexes. You could probably add some indexes and
  make it more performant... but indexes might not actually help in
  this instance, since you aren't querying over any duplicated rows.
- It might be possible to add compiler hints or use LEFT/RIGHT Joins to improve query plan execution. LEFT/RIGHT Joins in the wrong place could break the query, though.
- as it currently stands, you'd have to insert the queried number into the `contact` database and tokenize it and insert into `relation` and `token` prior to querying. Instead, you could use a temporary table for the queried tokens, then do `JOIN temp_tokens ON temp_tokens.token = all_tokens.token`... Actually, that's probably what you should do. But I'm not gonna re-write this answer right now.
- Using `integer` columns for `phone` and `token` would perform better, if that is a valid option for you.

---

An alternate way to do it, which would be better than inserting all the tokens into the table just for a query would be to use an `IN ()`, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact.phone FROM token
    JOIN relation 
        ON relation.token_id = token.id
    JOIN contact 
        ON relation.contact_id = contact.id
    WHERE token.token IN ('123','234','345','and so on')
```

And here is another, improved fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48d0e/2